# Angular 2 basic test fails

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am getting started with Angular2 and testing: Jasmine & Karma. I wrote a few sanity tests which worked fine but when I attempt a simple default injector test it fails:

```
using-injector.spec.ts

describe('default test injector', () => {
  it('should provide default id', inject([APP_ID], (id) => {
    expect(id).toBe('a');
  }));
});
```

The error I see in Karma:

```
Failed: No provider for Token AppId!
Error: DI Exception
    at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (C:/Users/f
ocuments/dev/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:7587:21) ...
```

Any hint would be highly appreciated

Comment: Did you  call `setTestProviders(...)` like shown in https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-6 ?

Comment: How do you define APP_ID?

Comment: Did you import the service? Instead of using an injector, you can just use the new keyboard to instantiate the service.

Comment: Worked ! I imported the setBaseTestProviders() right in the test, however I noticed in test angular2-test-seed project this import is in the "karma-test-shim.js". I am not sure, yet, if I will need this for my next test development..Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I would specify `APP_ID` within the `beforeEachProviders` function.

```
beforeEachProviders(() => [
  APP_ID
]);
```

Then you should be able to inject it.

Answer (score 0):

Imported

```
import {setBaseTestProviders} from 'angular2/testing';
import {
  TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
  TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
} from 'angular2/platform/testing/browser';
setBaseTestProviders(TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
                     TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);
```

in my test and worked.
Overall , I think this import should be in "karma-test-shim.js" see:
https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed